# TigerVNC Unable to Start Systemd Service

Tags: rhel, vnc, remote-desktop, alma-linux, tigervnc

I recently followed a guide I found here: [How to Install VNC Server on RHEL 8](https://www.tecmint.com/install-vnc-server-on-rhel-8/) to create a VNC session for a given user. I have since created a new user account: `engineer` and updated the systemd service file to point to the new user account as shown below:

```
[engineer@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service
[Unit]
Description=Remote Desktop Service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/engineer
User=engineer
Group=engineer

PIDFile=/home/engineer/.vnc/%H%i.pid

ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -autokill %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I created a new vnc password for the `engineer` account and then executed the `systemctl daemon-reload` command after creating my service file, then executed the command: `systemctl start vncserver@:1` as per the guide and now I get the follow error message:

```
Failed to import environment: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
```

Annoyingly everything was working fine until updated the `vncserver@` service file.

Interestingly if I revert all the settings in the service file back to the original user it works without fail.

Comment: can you add to the question the output of `systemctl --user status` and `systemctl --state=failed --all' ?

Comment: Hello @D'ArcyNader I tried to execute the first command you mentioned and the got the error: `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be an answer per se, but I found an simpler implementation of what I need based on information I have found from the following two sources, so I thought I'd share:

1. [How to configure VNC server in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-configure-vnc-server-red-hat-enterprise-linux-8)
2. [Tigervnc black screen](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=73174)

The steps below are under the assumption that you have installed `TigerVNC` and done nothing more.

Firstly I signed into the user account and created a vnc password by executing the command:

```
$ vncpasswd
```

I did not set a view only password when prompted.

Next I modified the `vncserver.user` file located in: `/etc/tigervnc/` and added my user by following the examples in the file.

After saving my changes I copied the user environment config template from the  `/etc/tigervnc/` directory to my user account `home` directory by executing the following command:

```
$ cp /etc/tigervnc/vncserver-config-mandatory ~/.vnc/config
```

After copying the template, I edited the `config` file to define my session and desired screen resolution:

```
session=xfce4-session
geometry=1920x1080
```

Next I copied the `systemd` service template by executing the command:

```
$ sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service
```

After copying the file to the correct directory I modified it with the following two lines:

```
Restart=on-success
RestartSec=15
```

The reasons I added these two line is I noticed that if you logout of the desktop environment while using the VNC session it will actually stop the `systemd` service file. These additional lines will check this and then restart the service after 15 seconds.

The final steps taken were to first start the `systemd` service by executing the command:

```
$ sudo systemctl start vncserver@:1
```

Then I checked the `systemd` service had started successfully via the command:

```
$ sudo systemctl status vncserver@:1
```

Once confirmed the `systemd` service had started I attempted a connection to the IP Address with the port: `5901`.

After I was happy with everything, I enabled the `systemd` service so that it starts during boot:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable vncserver@:1
```

I hope this information will be helpful to others.